# Setting MEDIA_URL for Django Heroku App, Amazon S3

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3

I've been attempting to set up a MEDIA_URL for my Heroku app, which is currently serving static files via STATIC_URL from Amazon S3. The static files are working fine, but when I attempt to add a MEDIA_URL in addition to the current STATIC_URL, the pages no longer render at all and the app ceases to work.

The current settings are:

```
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'bucketname'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
S3_URL = 'http://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
STATIC_URL = S3_URL
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'KEY'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'SECRET_KEY'
```

When I add:

```
MEDIA_URL = S3_URL
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
```

that causes the issue. Specifically, the MEDIA_URL is problematic as when DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE is deleted, it still has the same issue. But I'm trying to determine best how to serve user uploaded media through this unsuccessfully.

If anyone has any insight how best to achieve this, it would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

STATIC_URL and MEDIA_URL can't have the same value, it raises an error.

I had/still have the same problem and couldn't find a clean way to do it. Wait for a better answer, but this is how I solved it (ugly hack):

I'm using [django_storages](http://code.larlet.fr/django-storages/) and [django_compressor](https://github.com/jezdez/django_compressor). Since the media files appear in the root of my S3 bucket I can access them through STATIC_URL. In my settings.py:

```
COMPRESS_URL = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/"
STATIC_URL = COMPRESS_URL
```

In my local dev environment I use MEDIA_URL and for production STATIC_URL. Set an environmental variable that has the value True for your local env and False on Heroku and put it in a context_processor env.

Then you can access the media files in your templates like this:

```
background-image: url({% if env == 'True' %}{{ MEDIA_URL }}{% else %}{{ STATIC_URL }}{% endif %}{{ course.image }});
```

It works, but it is ugly. Hopefully somebody found a better solution so I ran refactor my code :)

**edit**
There's a better way: [this app](https://github.com/jamstooks/django-s3-folder-storage) lets you create a static and a media folder in S3.

Comment: I ended up setting just DEFAULT_FILE_STORAG, which sort of half works. Some media is going directly to Amazon S3 (user submitted images) while other stuff isn't. Photos using sorlthumbnail are totally failing, though. Your way might work.

Comment: I spend some more time on this and I found a way that works just fine: I used [this small app](https://github.com/jamstooks/django-s3-folder-storage) that lets you have a static and a media folder in your S3 bucket. Hope that helps!

Comment: How does this deal with security? Aren't all the files public?

Answer (score 4):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390244/how-to-set-up-a-django-project-with-django-storages-and-amazon-s3-but-with-diff/10825691#10825691) solution works quite well, as described below.

Create a file called `s3utils.py` in the same directory as `settings.py`:

```
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage

StaticRootS3BotoStorage = lambda: S3BotoStorage(location='static')
MediaRootS3BotoStorage  = lambda: S3BotoStorage(location='media')
```

Then in `settings.py`:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'myproyect.s3utils.MediaRootS3BotoStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'myproyect.s3utils.StaticRootS3BotoStorage'
```

Comment: Worked for me, but also needed to add a couple lines to sync with output of the static and media files:  S3_URL = 'http://' + AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME + '.s3.amazonaws.com/'
 STATIC_URL = S3_URL + 'static/'
 MEDIA_URL = S3_URL + 'media/'