# How to use Dropbox as Django media files storage?

Tags: django, upload, storage, media, dropbox

Is there a clean way of using Dropbox as storage for django media files?. Like you would do with **s3boto** and **AmazonS3** described here: [How to set-up a Django project with django-storages and Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390244/how-to-set-up-a-django-project-with-django-storages-and-amazon-s3-but-with-diff)

Thanks

Comment: Aside from rolling your own, there doesn't appear to be very many solutions. See: https://www.djangopackages.com/search/?q=dropbox and http://agiliq.com/blog/2012/07/dropbox-file-upload-handler-for-django/

Comment: That could work, it's a very simple Facebook Tab App. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`django-storages` has a dropbox implementation ready to go, just:

```
pip install dropbox django-storages
```

and in your settings file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS += (
    'storages',
)

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.dropbox.DropBoxStorage'
```

From: http://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/dropbox.html