# Django heroku files

Tags: django, heroku, media

So, I have set up an upload feature in my admin where an admin can upload photos. These photos are accessed via a view such that an admin can use them. I deployed this to heroku. So far it seems to work where if I upload a photo, it gets linked to the view, and it shows up.

My MEDIA_URL ='/media/' and my MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR , 'media') and at the moment, DEBUG = True for my case.
So the problem is this: After leaving the site for a couple of hours or so, when I try to access the files, it seems to have changed the link and the photos are no longer linked.

Is there a way to fix this such that when I leave for some time, the link to the photos do not change? (I don't see a solution based on google, and it seems that people have not run into this problem...unless I'm google crippled :/ )

Comment: Where are they being uploaded to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized my issue. They're being uploaded to the media folders that live in Heroku which is not the way to go. instead I used amazon aws s3 to serve both the media files and static files. Here's a link that answered my question:

[django heroku media files 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578735/django-heroku-media-files-404-error)

However, I'm thinking of switching to using smartfile because it's free :D