# Heroku: Django database file lost on every dyno restart

Tags: django, sqlite, heroku, persistence

I deployed a Django app on Heroku. I have some models and inserted some data to the database (SQLite database). But, when I tried to access the data after certain time, it showing an empty database. I found a problem similar to my issue here ->[django heroku media files 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578735/django-heroku-media-files-404-error#) and I understood that, I should keep my Media files somewhwere else. 
Here my problem is with database and my question is, can I prevent my **SQLite database** from this data loss ?

Answer (score 7):

There is nothing you can do about this, short of storing the database on some other service like Amazon S3. Heroku has ephemeral storage: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3#disk-backed-storage

However, Heroku also comes with free persistent PostgreSQL. So I would advice you to use that instead.