# How can I upload images to amazon S3 with django-storages? Uploading in admin works but in the website form does not

Tags: python, django, django-storage

For some reason, django-storages is giving me problems uploading images to S3 from a from on my site. When I upload an image through admin, the image will be fine, but if I upload it through my site it will show up on S3, but will say "image failed to load". Because my site is going to take user uploaded images as well as serve staticfiles from S3, I followed [this model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390244/how-to-set-up-a-django-project-with-django-storages-and-amazon-s3-but-with-diff%5B1%5D) on StackOverflow

Python 2.7, Django 1.5.5

Anyone have ideas on what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone seeing this in the future, I found the issue. I had overridden methods to check the file size and resize the image that I removed and it now works