# Django static file URLS are broken

Tags: python, django, heroku, amazon-s3, boto

I am using Boto2 to help with s3 integration with my Django-admin app on heroku. Some of the urls are being generated incorrectly for my static files.
Example:

`https://BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com/FOLDER/static/admin?Signature=XXX&Expires=YYY&AWSAccessKeyId=ZZZimg/icon_calendar.gif`

When it should be

`https://BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com/FOLDER/static/admin/img/icon_calendar.gif?Signature=XXX&Expires=YYY&AWSAccessKeyId=ZZZ`

Notice that `img/icon_calendar.gif` is out of place. The only thing I can think that is causing this issue is the code I used to make the static files on a sub folder in my bucket. It is based on [this SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10825691/1449607)

```
#s3utils.py
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage
import  os

STATIC_ROOT = 'FOLDER/static'
MEDIA_ROOT = 'FOLDER/media'

StaticRootS3BotoStorage = lambda: S3BotoStorage(location=STATIC_ROOT)
MediaRootS3BotoStorage  = lambda: S3BotoStorage(location=MEDIA_ROOT)

#settings.py
...
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = "BUCKET"
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'ZZZ'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'AAAA'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'app.s3utils.MediaRootS3BotoStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'app.s3utils.StaticRootS3BotoStorage'

S3_URL = 'http://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/' % (AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)

STATIC_ROOT = '/FOLDER/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/FOLDER/media/'

STATIC_URL = '%sFOLDER/static/' % (S3_URL)
MEDIA_URL = '%sFOLDER/media/' % (S3_URL)
```

What could be causing the URLs to get corrupted?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem @datinc? I'm having the exact same setup and the exact same problem.

Comment: I did @espenhogbakk. I have set it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a fix in this [git repo](https://github.com/jamstooks/django-s3-folder-storage). My s3utils.py file now looks like

```
#s3utils.py
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage
import  os

STATIC_ROOT = 'FOLDER/static'
MEDIA_ROOT = 'FOLDER/media'

class FixedS3BotoStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    def url(self, name):
        url = super(FixedS3BotoStorage, self).url(name)
        if name.endswith('/') and not url.endswith('/'):
            url += '/'
        return url

StaticRootS3BotoStorage = lambda: FixedS3BotoStorage(location=STATIC_ROOT)
MediaRootS3BotoStorage  = lambda: FixedS3BotoStorage(location=MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('your_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('your_key')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'yourbucketname'
AWS_PRELOAD_METADATA = True #helps collectstatic do updates

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'

STATIC_URL = 'https://' + AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME + '.s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/folder/static'

MEDIA_URL = 'https://' + AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME + '.s3.amazonaws.com/ bucket/folder/media'
```

Comment: This system requires that folder structure looks like bucket/folder/static and bucket/folder/media. Using your setup does not allow for this structure

Comment: Using the new edits does not store the files in the folders specified.